# How to update one var in a selected list and set others zero?

Tags: mysql

I got the IDs(the rows to be updated) in this query from post table, with those IDs as rows in grade table, I want to set one var to 1, and others in this array to 0, and keep the rest rows in the grade table unchanged:

```
SELECT ID FROM posts
WHERE post_parent = ''
AND post_status IN ( '')
AND post_type = ''
```

I'd like to learn how to update the grade table as described above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
UPDATE grade g
JOIN   post p ON g.id          = p.id
             AND p.post_parent = $parent_id
             AND p.post_status = $post_status
             AND p.post_type   = $post_type
SET    g.grade = CASE WHEN g.id = $id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: there are an array of ids selected from another table. Do you mean <id> is an id value?

Comment: @Jenny How are you retrieving this 'array' of ids? Is it in another SELECT? Can you give an example of your data and what you want to update?

Comment: @Jenny, it sounds like you want to update the entire grade table, but set 1 to grade of the selected ids and 0 to all the rest. See my updated solution.

Comment: no, the grade table has other rows. I just updated my question again. the IDs are to be updated-- one to 1, others to zero, and keep the rest of rows in grade table unchanged.

Comment: @Jenny How do you know which particular `ID` you want to set to `1`? Is it going to be a variable passed in from PHP?

Comment: It looks like this code going to set all other rows in grade table to be zero? I want something like this--- grade table has 100 rows, I only updated 10 row, among the 10 row, set one to 1, set 9 to 0. Then, I still have 90 rows in grade table unchanged.

Comment: @Jenny, the `JOIN` will filter it down to only the rows that will be updated (id's selected based on the join condition - the same as your `SELECT` example). Once that happens, the CASE statement updates all but one row to 0.

Comment: @Jenny: Going a bit more MySQL-specific, you could also replace the CASE expression in this answer with just `g.id = $id`, i.e. `UPDATE ... SET g.grade = (g.id = $id)`. (The parentheses are most likely optional here, but it may look less ambiguous with them.)

Comment: @AndriyM , those IDs are children under one parent. When one child is set to 1, others need to be set to zero. So, if use the replacement you suggest above, other children won't be updated.

Comment: @Jenny: The replacement I suggested doesn't change the logic of the original answer. Sorry, perhaps I didn't make myself clear enough: I only suggest replacing the CASE expression, all the other parts of Zane's UPDATE statement remaining unchanged.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the additional tip!